# append a request body to vertx request

Tags: java, spring, vert.x

IN my java sample code of a vertex URL instance below, The URL returns a json request when called. I am trying to append a request body to the URL but I am stuck. Here is a sample snippet

```
Route handler2 = router
                .post("/get-a-file")
                .consumes("*/json")
                .handler(routingContext -> {
                    HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
                    response.setChunked(true);
                    response.write("bla bla bla...");
                    response.end();
                });
```

Just getting my hands on vert.x. Do assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For request bodies in Vert.x [your route needs a BodyHandler](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_request_body_handling). You should add it before your own handler so that the request body is already there when your business logic runs.

Your code should look similar to this:

```
...
.consumes("*/json")
.handler(BodyHandler.create())
.handler(routingContext -> ...
```

Now you can access the body on `routingContext` and map it to your DTO.

Comment: Thanks but I tried passing the dto back as response but its failing - response.write(myDto);

Comment: You would need to encode it first since `write` requires a string